# How do I install Atom text editor on a 32 bit Debian system?

Tags: software-installation, atom-editor

**How do I install the [Atom text editor](http://atom.io) on a 32 bit Debian system?**

Among the [releases](https://github.com/atom/atom/releases/tag/v1.6.2) I can only see a 64 bit version. Do I need to compile it myself to use it on a 32 bit system?

Comment: Related info for Ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/641239/how-i-can-create-a-32-bit-version-of-atom

Answer (score 2):

> Do I need to compile it myself to use it on a 32 bit system?

Short: Yes.

Long: Looking at...

- [github.com/atom/atom](https://github.com/atom/atom)
- [github.com/atom/atom/releases](https://github.com/atom/atom/releases)
- [github.com/atom/atom/blob/master/docs/build-instructions/linux.md](https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/master/docs/build-instructions/linux.md)

...it really looks like there are no ready-to-download 32bit packages for Debian and other Linux flavours.

Answer (score 0):

32bit linux is not part of the official release cycle.

However, this project offers 32bit, up to date (03/2021) builds:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/atom-32-bit/

This is no PPA, so you have download and install the .deb file manually.

Update: There are up to date binaries and the announcement for a PPA here: https://atom32.aidanwebster.uk/